# Converting camelCase to underscore when deserializing an object using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization

I have a fixture file `person.json`,

```
{
   "fistName": "John"
   "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

I have a class called Person

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  //.. getters and setters
}
```

I deserialize `Person` using `ObjectMapper` like below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
Person person = mapper.readValue(new FileInputStream(new File("person.json")),Person.class);
```

I get this error,

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
Unrecognized field "firstName" (class com.foo.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "first_name", "last_name"])
```

I get the same error when I use
  `mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);`.

My question is Why do I get this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't get this error? What do you think `setPropertyNamingStrategy` accomplishes?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I knew it I wouldn't have asked the question. I get the same error without setting `setPropertyNamingStrategy`. I'll update the question

Comment: Recompile. Assuming your JSON is free of the typos it currently has, there should be no error, let alone the same error, when removing the `setPropertyNamingStrategy` call.

Comment: Recompiled, JSON is free of errors. I have worked with ObjectMappers before and understand basics. The puzzling thing is where those underscore fields are coming from.

Comment: They aren't fields, they are properties. If you use `CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`, then the property, by default named `firstName`, ie. camel case, is converted to lower case with underscores, ie. `first_name`. Without that naming strategy, the property (depending on what your getter is) remains `firstName`. If not, you're doing something else you aren't showing us.

Comment: Exactly how I understood. When I first saw the error with underscore properties, I thought I need to use `CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`. But no luck. I don't see underscore properties at all through out the project. It seems there is some magic setting in the project that is causing this error that I need to find.

Comment: Just to be sure: the getters and setters in `Person` do not use underscores either, right?

Comment: @hzpz nope no underscores in getters and setters

Answer (score 1):

Because you ask Jackson to use a [naming strategy](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.html) that translates camel case, i.e. `firstName` to lower case with underscore i.e. `first_name`.

---

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = mapper.readValue(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/person.json")),Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}

@Data // lombok @Data
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

and `person.json` (fixed):

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

Output:

```
Person(firstName=John, lastName=Smith)
```

Comment: I get the same error without setting the naming strategy for ObjectMapper. I'll update the question

Comment: Works for me when `setPropertyNamingStrategy` is not here. (jackson 2.6.0)

Comment: Sure, this is how I understand as well. However I'm puzzled as where those underscore fields are coming from. I'm new this app and it looks like there is some setting within the app thats causing this error.